# jQuery Validation plugin - How to validate area (square meter)?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have the following basic set up to calculate / validate area (square meters m2). What I need to know is how to write the JQuery to be able to do this? I have two input fields for "screen_width" and "screen_height".

Conditions are: Neither Width or Height may exceed 3m in length. Total area m2 may not exceed 4m2.(ie. 1500 mm x 3000 mm = 4.5m2) I don't mind the independent length checks for 3000, but I simply need an error output when the area exceeds 4m2 (width x height).

#### JQuery:

```
$("#area_form").validate({
    debug: true,        
    errorContainer: "#error-output",
    errorLabelContainer: "#error-output ul",
    wrapper: "li",
    rules: {
        screen_width: {
            required: true,
            digits: true,
            range: [1, 3000],
            maxlength: 4                        
        },
        screen_height: {
            required: true,
            digits: true,
            range: [1, 3000],
            maxlength: 4                        
        }
    },
    messages: {
        screen_width: {
            required: "Width required.",
            digits: "Digits only.",
            range: "Exceeding 3000mm.",
            maxlength: "Max 4 digits."                  
        },
        screen_height: {
            required: "Height required.",
            digits: "Digits only.",
            range: "Exceeding 3000mm.",
            maxlength: "Max 4 digits."                  
        }
    }
 });
```

#### HTML:

```
<form name="area_form" id="area_form" action="target.php" method="post">

<label for="screen_width">Screen Width</label>                
<input type="text" name="screen_width" id="screen_width" maxlength="4" autocomplete="off">

<label for="screen_height">Screen Height</label>
<input type="text" name="screen_height" id="screen_height" maxlength="4" autocomplete="off">

    <div id="error-ouput">
        <ul>
        </ul>
    </div>

</form>
```

I figured I probably need something like this, and then the actual calculations :

```
$.validator.messages.max = jQuery.validator.format("Your area may not exceed {0}!");
```

But beyond this point I'm lost, I hope I made it as clear as possible as to what I need. I'd appreciate any help thank you!

Comment: You don't need the attribute, `maxlength="4"`, within your HTML when you've already declared `maxlength: 4` within the `rules` option inside your `.validate()`.  If you happen to change the value of one or the other, your results might be unexpected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quote OP:**

> *"I figured I probably need something like this, and then the actual calculations:"*

```
$.validator.messages.max = jQuery.validator.format("Your area may not exceed {0}!"
```

Use the `param` argument here and it will be inserted in place of `{0}` within the message too...

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("maxsquare", function(value, element, params) {
    return ($('#screen_width').val() * $('#screen_height').val()) <= params[0];
}, jQuery.validator.format("Square area cannot exceed {0}."));
```

Within your `.validate()` ...

```
rules: {
    screen_width: {
        required: true,
        digits: true,
        range: [1, 3000],
        maxlength: 4,
        maxsquare: 4000000   // <-- set the rule & parameter                     
    },
    screen_height: {
        required: true,
        digits: true,
        range: [1, 3000],
        maxlength: 4,
        maxsquare: 4000000   // <-- set the rule & parameter
    }
},
```

See documentation: http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/

---

You *could* take it a step further and pass the other field name as another parameter and use the `element` and `value` arguments as designed.  This way, the method is more generic; it's not always tied to two particular fields.

```
rules: {
    screen_width: {
        required: true,
        digits: true,
        range: [1, 3000],
        maxlength: 4,
        maxsquare: ['#screen_height', 4000000]   // <-- set the rule & parameters                     
    },
    screen_height: {
        required: true,
        digits: true,
        range: [1, 3000],
        maxlength: 4,
        maxsquare: ['#screen_width', 4000000]   // <-- set the rule & parameters
    }
},
```

`maxsquare` Method:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("maxsquare", function(value, element, params) {
    return (value * $(params[0]).val()) <= params[1];
}, jQuery.validator.format("Square area cannot exceed {1}."));
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/scLhR/**

---

**Sidenote**:  You don't need the attribute, `maxlength="4"`, within your HTML when you've already declared `maxlength: 4` within the `rules` option inside your `.validate()`.  If you happen to change the value of one or the other, your results might be unexpected.

Comment: Thx mate really appreciate your help, works a charm.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("maxsquare", function(value, element) {
    return ($('#screen_width').val() * $('#screen_height').val()) <= 4000000;
}, "Max square...");
```

Comment: Brilliant! Ty vm, would uprate this if I could.

Comment: @TheRealWitblitz, you don't have the reputation to up-vote it, **HOWEVER**, you asked the question, so you always have the option to "accept" the best answer by clicking the green check-mark.